# Why stored function will always refer to the value of the updated global i variable?

Tags: function, variables, scope, var, let

```
var printNumTwo;
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  if (i === 2) {
    printNumTwo = function() {
      return i;
    };
  }
}
console.log(printNumTwo());
```

Why the printed value of i is 3 instead of 2?

Answer (score 1):

Because of `var` keyword, when you use `var` keyword for loop, It replace value instead of create  a  new value, where `i` created once and replaced by `i` on each iteration... you should use `let` or `const` to expect your desire output.

example:

using `let` keyword

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    setTimeout(() => console.log(i), i * 100)
}
```

Here we used `var` keyword

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    setTimeout(() => console.log(i), i * 100)
}
```

In Another word, In JavaScript using `var` keyword to declare a variable create a variable in function or closure scope, instead of block scope.